# How to get rid of $(\frac{dw}{dx})^2$ term in a differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

My try:

> $$y=w^{-1}$$
>
> $$y'=-w^{-2} \frac{dw}{dx}$$
>
> $$y''=\frac{2}{w^3} \frac{dw}{dx} - \frac{1}{w^2} \frac {d^2w}{dx^2}$$

Substituting these to the first expression :

$$\frac{2}{w^4}\frac{dw}{dx}-\frac{1}{w^3}\frac{d^2w}{dx^2}-\frac{2}{w^3}\frac{dw}{dx}-\frac{2}{w^4}(\frac{dw}{dx})^2-\frac{5}{w^2}=(5x^2+4x+2)\frac{1}{w^3}$$

---

I don't know how to get rid of the "squared" term:

$$-\frac{2}{w^4}(\frac{dw}{dx})^2$$

Since the required expression doesn't have  a squared term. Please help.

Comment: Seems to me you've got a wrong sign there. $2yy' = 2w^{-1} (-w^{-2})w'$, so this term is $-2w^{-3}w'$. You got a plus sign there.

Comment: @IvoTerek Thanks :) fixed the typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that I found a mistake $$y=\frac{1}{w(x)}$$ $$y'=-\frac{w'(x)}{w(x)^2}$$ $$y''=\frac{2 w'(x)^2}{w(x)^3}-\frac{w''(x)}{w(x)^2}$$

I am sure that you can take from here.

Comment: Got it :D thank you :)

Comment: You are very welcome :-)

Comment: (+1) You have a stunning reputation level. Great work :)